# Javascript:DIV AppendChild

Tags: javascript, appendchild

In the below code `"objTo"` is a div to which i need to insert multiple number of div.
when i use the code for the first time its working.but on the next time its overwriting      the existing code.

```
     <script>

var divtest= document.createElement("div");        
divtest.innerHTML = "<div>new div</div>"         
objTo.appendChild(divtest)
    </script>
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Running that code multiple times won't overwrite anything (other then a reference that you no longer need). I suspect you have created a reduced test case that has reduced away the problem.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have made a very simple working version for you :

http://jsfiddle.net/hQKy9/

Multiple clicks works the whole time :

**Script**

```
function addDiv() {
    var objTo = document.getElementById('container');
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = "new div";
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
}
```

**Html**

```
<div id="container"></div>

<input type="button" onclick="addDiv();" value="Click here to add div"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even through Marc gave the ans before
I found it we can do more like adding ID/Class and CSS like the following way I did

```
const newChild = document.createElement('div');
newChild.id = 'newly_content';
newChild.innerHTML = `
    <p style="font-size: 30px;padding: 200px 0px 10px 0px;">
        A new content has been created!
    </p>
`;
document.getElementById('ItemID').appendChild(newChild);
```