# Changing from input (type "button") to button tag does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328210/javascriptdiv-appendchild) on Stackoverflow. The accepted answer has a Fiddle attached to it. I tried to tweak the code a little by changing the button "type" to the button tag and came up with this Fiddle. But I don't know why this is not working. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Original Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hQKy9/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="addDiv();" value="Click here to add div"/>
```

**Script**

```
function addDiv() {
    var objTo = document.getElementById('container');
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = "new div";
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
}
```

My Version: https://jsfiddle.net/Miraj50/gdjpbewx/1/

**HTML**

```
<button class="but">hello</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Script**

```
var adddiv = document.querySelector('.but');
adddiv.addEventListener('click',addDiv);

function addDiv() {
    var objTo = document.getElementById('container');
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.innerHTML = "new div";
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
}
```

Comment: In fiddle, change load type to "onDomready".

Comment: Always specify the type attribute for a <button> element. Different browsers use different default types for the <button> element.

Comment: Here's how it would look if you had only changed the input to button: https://jsfiddle.net/hQKy9/815/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code in window.onload, like so:

This will allow the items to load, after that you can bind your events.

```
window.onload = function() {

var adddiv = document.querySelector('.but');
adddiv.addEventListener('click',addDiv);

function addDiv() {
        var objTo = document.getElementById('container');
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.innerHTML = "new div";
        objTo.appendChild(divtest);
}

}
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks, Didn't come across this function before.

Comment: Also Thanks to @Nisarg Shah for telling me one more way to do it!

Comment: Glad I could help.